# How will Trinity or any other IOTA wallet keep up with hundreds of local snapshots per day?

Tags: wallet, snapshot, node, local

So lets assume that in few years, each node is gonna make 50 or 100 snapshots each day. Trinity is gonna keep local data on each account like addresses, balance, etc.. while at the same time automatically switching between nodes which means that each node will be in a different state. *How will we as users be 100% sure that our local data matches 100% the actual tangle data at all times?* I can't see a way where we have the entire tangle running with hundreds of thousands of transactions per second, millions of devices doing hundreds of local snapshots per day, economic clustering and sharded nodes **and all our wallets 100% keeping up with all of that and staying in sync**. Please enlighten me if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Nodes will not be in different states **regarding your balance** as long as you don‘t sign bundles.

So you can be 100% sure that you have ***X*** Iotas on `ADDRESS9` and you can be 100% sure that you have ***X-Y*** Iotas on `ADDRESS9` after you sign and publish a bundle that spends ***Y*** Iotas from `ADDRESS9`

It makes no difference, if a node does 7 or 700 snapshots a day or if there are 10 or 10000 TPS as long as none of them spend from `ADDRESS9`. Switching between nodes will also not decrease the balance of `ADDRESS9`.